# Can a person only send large amounts an have a $500 transaction log between us before he could send? How can i get around this?

Tags: exchanges

Recently I going to receive a donation from a man and he tried sending a large amount. The amount wouldn't send he said we had to have at least $500 in transactions before it would go thru. Does this make sense ? He said he could only send large amounts. How can I receive the donation without the transaction log?

Comment: Seem like a scam

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a scam; that's not how Bitcoin works. I wouldn't have high expectations about the outcome of this. The goal is to get you to send them money.

---

I would say the following:

- Send me the $500 and I'll partly refund you once your transaction is confirmed.

This is because, unlike bank transactions, transactions in Bitcoin are irreversible and it's not possible for them to "transact and cancel the transactions".

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make any sense at all. This is a 100% scam. Don't trust this person. Block him forever and don't reply to his messages. Cryptocurrency transactions don't require any backlog history.